# Upload multiple files from Smartphones via file upload

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, file-upload

I ran into a problem with file upload on smartphones. 
My Website needs multiple pdfs from one file upload. On smartphones (just tested iPhone until now) i can select multiple images, but when i browse my files app I only can select one pdf. Does somebody ran into a similar problem and knows how to fix it? Or is the only solution adding a "Upload more" button?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm this doesn't look like it's limited to react. I have tried as well and it appears to be a bug in the file picker on iOS.  An 'Upload More' button is what I had to implement to get it to work.

Comment: @IvanKahl yeah okay this is what I thought too. Thanks for the confirmation.